# Reconstruct signal from its Spectrogram only

Tags: spectrogram, stft, time-frequency, reconstruction

The spectrogram of a signal throws away the phase information, but it is said to be possible to reconstruct the signal only from the spectrogram [1] via
$$s(t) = \frac{1}{2\pi s^*(0)}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{M_{SP}(\theta,t)}{A_h(-\theta,t)}e^{-j\theta t/2}d\theta$$ where $M_{SP}$ is the chariteristic function of spectrogram and ${A_h(\theta,t)}$ is the ambiguity function of the window.

The formula seems to work in theory. Could anybody explain why it works? Some phase information is thrown away after all. Also, is it a good reconstruction tool used in practice? It seems to me that nobody uses this as the reconstruction tool.

[[1] L. Cohen, Time-frequency analysis. Englewood Cliffs, N.J: Prentice Hall PTR, 1995.](http://www.worldcat.org/title/time-frequency-analysis/oclc/801304211?loc=)

Comment: I've got that book. Which page?

Comment: In my edition (1995), p. 108, section 7.9, formula 7.94

Comment: Does anybody know why?

Comment: What are the integration limits? What variable are we supposed to integrate ($\mathrm{d}\theta$, I suppose)?

Comment: Sorry for missing this information. It has been edited.